# How to get video/x-raw from GstCaps

Tags: gstreamer

I'm trying to support all camera drivers but I need to separate from audio and video drivers. So I need to get 
video/x-raw,   image/jpeg  from GstCaps element but I couldn't find anything on the internet how to get only video/x-raw from GstCaps.

I know how to get height and width from GstCaps 
gst_structure_get_int(s, "height", &height);
gst_structure_get_int(s, "width", &width);

But I don't know how to get 
"video/x-raw",
"image/jpeg",
"application/x-rtp"
 What is the function of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `gst_structure_get_name (const GstStructure *structure);`

```
const gchar *media_type = gst_structure_get_name (s);
g_print("media_type is: %s\n", media_type);
```